# How to remove zero value (0) value to months with single digit in r?

Tags: r, date, time-series, date-format, lubridate

I am working with time series data with date format of YMD, I would like to remove zero value to months with single digit (January - September). How to I remove it in r?

This is a sample of my current date format: "2009-05-01" "2009-06-01" "2009-07-01" "2009-08-01" "2009-09-01". I want my date format to be like this: "2009-5-01" "2009-6-01" "2009-7-01" "2009-8-01" "2009-9-01".
Any help please of removing zero value by r code

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this regex :

```
x <- c("2009-05-01", "2009-06-01", "2009-07-01", "2009-08-01", "2009-10-01")
sub('(\\d+-)0?(.*)', '\\1\\2', x)
#[1] "2009-5-01"  "2009-6-01"  "2009-7-01"  "2009-8-01"  "2009-10-01"
```

The logic here is to extract data in two capture groups. The first capture group extract the year value with `-` and second capture group has everything else ignoring an optional zero if present.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lubridate` with `sprintf`

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("2009-05-01", "2009-06-01", "2009-07-1", "2009-08-01", "2009-1-01")
x <- ymd(x)
sprintf("%d-%d-%02d", year(x), month(x), day(x))
```

Output

```
[1] "2009-5-01" "2009-6-01" "2009-7-01" "2009-8-01" "2009-1-01"
```